# Unicode font not showing correctly on Chrome

Tags: css, wordpress, google-chrome, unicode, fonts

I'm using local font Meera.ttf, MEERA0.eot on my current website which is Malayalam (a local language in India). Now the problem is the large posts showing some big fonts in Chrome, but it works perfectly in all other browsers. Other content works perfectly in both Chrome and other browsers. Attaching two screenshots. The first one is Chrome and the second is Firefox.

---

#### Chrome

[image: on Chrome]

---

#### Firefox

[image: On firefox]

---

This happened on so many pages. But if the content is short, it works nicely.

For reference, the site is on Wordpress.

Comment: I saw the problem. But have no idea how this is happening. hope someone will find an answer. +1 for the question

Comment: I'm using the dev channel of Chrome (v20) on OS X and this appears to have been fixed.

Comment: I am viewing on Chrome(18) on Windows. Still there is problem.

Comment: On 2012-05-13, using Chrome 18.0.1025.168 (which Chrome claims is up to date) on Mac OS X 10.7.4, the web site shows uniformly sized Malayalam text where the screen shot shows big text.  That's just a data point: some versions of Chrome on some platforms handle it correctly.  There may be hope that your versions of Chrome will be fixed soon.

Comment: I too using same version 18.0.1025.168 and chrome says its latest version. Maybe your OS...So this is not a known issue right? Its gonna be a main problem for me in the future..

Answer (score 0):

The [W3C Markup Validator](http://validator.w3.org) finds 101 markup errors on the page and additionally issues 10 warnings. The page structure is rather contrived, and it does some browser sniffing and tries to serve different style sheets for different browsers. It is very difficult to say whether these have something to do with the problem observed. It is probably a major effort to track down the cause of the problem, and having that many markup errors makes a page rather fragile.

I’m afraid the obvious answer “simplify the structure and fix the markup errors first” is not very realistic, but it might be the best advice you can get.

Comment: problem solved. The current update of chrome looks fine. Thanks for the help guys